# What is the most efficient way to keep data synchronized between two locations?

Tags: backup, synchronization, files

For example, I would like to keep a lot of music files synchronized on two different hard drives.  What is the most efficient way to do this?  The more automated the method, the better!

Comment: What is the Operation System?

Answer (score 6):

rsync is pretty standard

unison is good if you want to transfer data in both directions

Comment: I use rsync at my company.

Answer (score 4):

I've been using [GetDropBox](https://www.getdropbox.com/) for some time to synchronize files across machines.  Its up and running now and runs across Windows, Mac, and Linux boxes.

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of options to do that. From simply using rSync tool to a lot of paid and free software. Here is a small list to get you started (assuming Windows OS) :

Free Versions

- [Syncback SE](http://www.2brightsparks.com/syncback/sbse.html)
- [Fling](http://www.nchsoftware.com/ftp/index.html)
- [Microsoft Synctoy](http://lifehacker.com/software/featured-windows-download/synchronize-folders-with-synctoy-20-326199.php)
- [Allways Sync](http://allwaysync.com/)

Paid

- [Goodsync](http://www.goodsync.com/)
- [SyncBack Pro](http://www.2brightsparks.com/syncback/sbpro.html)

Answer (score 1):

For a Windows system where you're wanting to do it across the internet, Live Mesh is pretty good; if you're syncing folders that are accessible from one machine (ie server to laptop) then SyncToy is a really good piece of software.

Answer (score 1):

For simple syncing between multiple computers, I used to use FolderShare, which is now [Windows Live Sync](https://www.foldershare.com/).  Works over a local network or the Internet, but is limited to 20,000 files per "library".  It's free.

I'm now using [SugarSync](http://www.sugarsync.com), which also syncs multiple computers but in addition maintains copies of all files on their servers as well for backup and/or for accessing the files from a non-synced machine.  They've got a 45-day free trial but after that you pay based on how many gigs you're syncing.  I'm on the $100/year 60GB plan.  Because all files are necessarily synced to the cloud, it's not nearly as speedy as Live Sync if all your synced machines are on the same local network.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows based systems, take a look at [MirrorFolder](http://www.techsoftpl.com/backup/index.php).  We use it as a backup to the backup on some servers.  Works quite well and is very easy to use and setup.  It's not free, but it is only $40.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Folders Synchronizer (by [softoBe](http://www.softobe.com/products/flsy/pp.html)) works great on my Mac.